# Strategy Pattern for GUI Program

Tags: java

So I'm tasked with doing the GUI portion of a Mancala game. I need to use the strategy pattern so that the user can choose between two styles of board design and so that there is a potential to add more boards later on. Looking at some tutorials, I devised the following bare skeleton:

Board.java interface

```
public interface Board {

    String board();
}

class Classic implements Board{

    @Override
    public String board() { 
        return "Classic";
    }
}

class Zelda implements Board{

    @Override
    public String board() {
        return "Zelda";
    }

}
```

MancalaBoard.java

```
public class MancalaBoard extends JComponent {

    private static final int DEFAULT_WIDTH =  Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width; //sets the width to the users screen dimension
    private static final int DEFAULT_HEIGHT =  Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height; //sets the height to the users screen dimension
    private static final int BOARD_WIDTH = DEFAULT_WIDTH - 100;
    private static final int BOARD_HEIGHT = DEFAULT_HEIGHT - 100;
    private static int pits;
    private int stones;
    public Board boardType;
    private JButton undoButton;

    public MancalaBoard(int stones){
        Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mancala Game");
        frame.setSize(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //frame.setLocation((screen.width - 500) / 2, (screen.height - 300) / 2);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        pits = 14;
        this.stones = stones; // user specified amount, no greater than 4

    }

    public String selectBoard(){
        return boardType.board();
    }

    public void setBoardType(Board newBoardType){
        boardType = newBoardType;
    }   

}
```

ClassicBoard.java

```
public class ClassicBoard extends MancalaBoard {

    public ClassicBoard(){
        super(4);
        boardType = new Classic();
    }

    public Double boardShape(){
        return new Rectangle2D.Double();
    }
```

ZeldaBoard.java (yep,I'm nerdy)

```
public class ZeldaBoard extends MancalaBoard {

    public ZeldaBoard(){
        super(4);
        boardType = new Zelda();
    }
    //board shape will be an ellipse
}
```

MancalaTester.java

```
public class MancalaTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        MancalaBoard myMancala = new MancalaBoard(4);
        myMancala.setBoardType(new Classic());
        System.out.println("myMancala: " + myMancala.selectBoard());

    }

}
```

So I'm able to use polymorphism in my tester to get the correct string to print which is nice, but I've hit a roadblock. Either I'm having a brain fart or I don't fully understand strategy pattern, but here is my question: How do I determine which class is responsible for what? I mean, they both have the same amount of pits, they will both have "undo button", but the aesthetic design will be different. Where do I specify those changes? For example, at the very core of it, my ClassicBoard is going to be a rectangle and my ZeldaBoard will be an ellipse. Do I write that in the Board.java classes, or do I write it in the ClassicBoard and ZeldaBoard respectively. Or is it factored to the MancalaBoard.java and decided there based on if the user selected Classic board or Zelda board?

Sorry for the rant, but I hope it makes sense. I just need someone to point me in the right direction about which class will be responsible for what.

Comment: Usually a strategy pattern will require an interface that each concrete strategy would need to implement. I would think that this would necessarily be part of your model, and that your view, your GUI, would respond to changes in model state by changing its display. I would imagine that your two states would be best modeled with an enum.

Comment: I have an interface called Board. How would I use the enum? Do I add all the components in it to draw in the frame?

Comment: The enum would be a marker for what state your in. It could be as simple as `enum MancalaState { CLASSIC, ZELDA}`. As to your drawing components, perhaps you want to use a CardLayout to swap JPanels, with each JPanel representing one board state.

Comment: The state won't change in the middle of the game. There is just going to be a dialogue box asking the user to select a version of the board before the game begins.